# Where to view echoed string when running Apache

Tags: php, apache, echo

I am running Apache on a MAC with

$ apachectl start

The index.html is at /Library/WebServer/Documents

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>blah</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>test html file: hello world</p>
  <button type="button" name="button" action="contact.php">Press me</button>

</body>

</html>
```

That page displays in the browser at port 80.

It should call a contact.php file when the button is pressed and this simple echoes a string. But where should I be able to see this string and so be able to check that contact.php is being called and running as expected?

contact.php

```
<?php

echo "blah1234567890";

?>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Yes this is a duplicate, but I didn't realise the problem was that I was using the button as a link and should have been using the form and input tags. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use :

```
<form action="contact.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Press me">
</form>
```

instead of :

```
<button type="button" name="button" action="contact.php">Press me</button>
```

in your `index.html` file.

With the `formaction` attribute you can specify multiple submit URLs for one form. Because the action attribute is no longer required for the form element you could define the submit URL(s) just in the `formaction` of a submit button. When the `form` is submitted, the browser first checks for a `formaction` attribute; if that isn’t present, it proceeds to look for an action attribute on the form element.

Comment: Great that works and the string is displayed in the browser itself. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`action` is not a valid attribute of the `button` element in html5.

Here is one option to make the button act like a link (if that's what you're trying to achieve) using the `onclick` attribute:

```
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="window.location.href='contact.php';">Press me</button>
```